# Import Error: playsound('D:\\Music\\abc.mp3') works in REPL but not in VS Code

Tags: python

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('D:\\Music\\abc.mp3')
```

It works in REPL but could make it work in VS Code. Using Python 3.10.0, Playsound 1.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, solved when downgraded playsound to version 1.2.2

```
pip uninstall playsound
pip install playsound==1.2.2
```

restart VSCode and run.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad Sulaiman, it worked. JazakaAllah